# Custom computation expressions in F#

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I've been toying with monads in F# (aka computation expressions) and I wrote this simple Identity monad:

```
type Identity<'a> = 
    | Identity of 'a

type IdentityBuilder() =
    member x.Bind (Identity v) f  = f(v)
    member x.Return v = Identity v
let identity = new IdentityBuilder()

let getInt() = identity { return Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) }

let calcs() = identity {
    let! a = getInt()    // <- I get an error here
    let! b = getInt()
    return a + b }
```

I don't understand the error I'm getting in the marked line:

> This expression was expected to have type Identity<'a> but here has type 'b * 'c

I think this makes no sense as getInt() is clearly a value of type `Identity<'a>`.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The computation expression syntax wants `Bind` to have a tupled, not curried argument.
So

```
member x.Bind((Identity v), f) = f(v)
```

See [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions) for all signatures.

Comment: Or see section 6.4.10 of the language spec:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html

Comment: Note to self: revise that wiki page because it makes no sense ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the type of your `Bind` function - it shouldn't take curried arguments.  If you change it to:

```
member x.Bind (Identity v, f)  = f(v)
```

then it should work.